# Entity Framework 6 - update fails (disconnected scenario)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to update an instance with Entity Framework 6. I suppose it's a disconnected scenario. And the update fails - no errors but the properties I change do not save in DB.

**Method in controller**

```
var managers = _iManagerRepository.Managers.ToList();
            var manager = managers.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == currentUserId);
            if (manager != null)
            {

                manager.ContactDetail.FirstName = withTokenDto.managerInfoModel.FirstName;
                manager.ContactDetail.SecondName = withTokenDto.managerInfoModel.SecondName;
                manager.ContactDetail.LastName = withTokenDto.managerInfoModel.LastName;

                _iManagerRepository.UpdateManager(manager);
                return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK));
            }
```

**Method in repository:**

```
public void UpdateManager(Manager manager)
    {
        using (LightCRMEntities context = new LightCRMEntities())
        {
            context.Managers.Attach(manager);
            context.Entry<Manager>(manager).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are missing a `context.Entry(manager.ContactDetail).State = EntityState.Modified;`. However, your code is terribly inefficient

Comment: Thx! It helped! So if any property is modified in disconnected scenario - you should explicitly point property that has been modified instead of just poiting to the parent instance? What is inefficient in my code?

Comment: The problem is that you are modifying a related entity that is not being tracked. Inefficient is that you are loading everything (`Managers.ToList()`) just to get one value (`FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == currentUserId)`), that should be done in the database. Also, you are creating a context to get the data, disposing it and then creating another context to update the data. Besides being inefficient this presents the kind of problems you are facing on this question

Comment: its because, does your Repository have the same context as your UpdateManager the answer is no.... as i can see you created a context in UpdateManager. Saying that you did update the state... but i would argue just put a save method on your repo and reuse the same context. Also you are fetching all your managers to update one. Lots in here which can improve..., sozs i see others are already saying all this...

Comment: Thanks @CamiloTerevinto and @Seabizkit Now I'm doing it all in one context. **controller:** `_iManagerRepository.UpdateManager(withTokenDto.managerInfoModel, currentUserId);` **repo:** `using (LightCRMEntities context = new LightCRMEntities())
            {
                var manager = context.Managers.Include(m => m.ContactDetail).FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == currentUserId);
                if (manager != null)
                {
                    manager.ContactDetail.FirstName = managerInfoModel.FirstName;
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }`